# Instances of objects in a class

Tags: php, forms, class, object

I have a form building a processing class that I have developed to handle any and all form processing on a page.

I am running into a problem when I have mulitple forms on a page I am building each form with an instance of the class:

```
    $form2 = new newForm('submitform2', 'post.contact.php', '100%');
$form2->setHandler('#canWe');
$form2->html('<div class="half">');
$form2->addText('name', 'Name:');
$form2->html('</div>');
$form2->html('<div class="halfNoMarg">');
$form2->addEmail('email_address', 'E-Mail Address:');
$form2->html('</div>');
$form2->html('<div class="half">');
$form2->addUrl('website', 'Website URL:');
$form2->html('</div>');
$form2->html('<div class="halfNoMarg">');
$form2->addText('phone', 'Phone Number:');
$form2->html('</div>');
$form2->addTextArea('about_business', 'Tell Us About Your Business:');

$form2->addSubmitButton('Find Out Now!');

$form2->getPost();
$form2->outputForm();
```

AND

```
    $form = new newForm('submitform', 'post.contact.php', '100%');
$form->addText('name', 'Name:');
$form->addEmail('email_address', 'E-Mail Address:');
$form->addUrl('website', 'Website URL:');
$form->addText('phone', 'Phone Number:');
$form->addTextArea('about_business', 'Tell Us About Your Business:');

$form->addSubmitButton('Find Out Now!');

$form->getPost();
$form->outputForm();
```

When the class processes the form and spits out the errors for the missing fields etc. each of the forms displays the errors and not just the form object that is being processed.

Basically the output is affecting each instance of the class and not just the one being processed.

I can include the class file if anyone needs it to help out (its 650 lines so didn't want to include in the post).

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

~M

EDIT ADDING IN THE POST FUNCTION

//get the post data and return a cleaned array of information if the post passes the pre check
public function getPost()
{

```
//if post tests all passed then lets create the array of elements and load the processing file.
if ($this->checkPost() === true) {

    $cleanedPost = $this->cleanPost;

    //get the post processing file
    if (file_exists($this->processFile)) {
        require_once($this->processFile);
        //$this->postMessage($this->successMessage, 'confirm');
    } else {
        $this->postMessage('Processing File Not Found:<em>' . $this->processFile . '</em>', 'error');
    }

    return $this->cleanPost;

} else {

    return false;
}
```

}

//output the form to the screen
public function outputForm()
{
    //echo spl_object_hash($this);

```
if($this->handler !== null){
    $this->handler = 'action="'.$this->handler.'"';
}

$return = '<form id="' . $this->formName . '" method="' . $this->method . '"'. $this->handler .' enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:' . $this->width . '" >';
if(!empty($this->message)){
    $return .= '<div class="errorMessage">' . $this->message . '</div>';
}
$return .= $this->output;
$return .= '</form>';

echo $return;
```

}

more post handling code

//check post before we handle it
public function checkPost()
{

```
//go through the entire post and process information as needed
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    foreach ($this->postCheck AS $postVar => $item) {

        if (is_array($item)) {

            //addItemTo cleanPost
            if(isset($_POST[$postVar])){
                $this->addToCleanedPost($postVar, $_POST[$postVar]);
            }else{
                $this->cleanPost[$postVar] = null;
            }

            switch ($item['type']) {

                //validate emails
                case 'email':
                    //check valid email
                    if (isset($this->cleanPost[$postVar]) && !$this->validEmail($this->cleanPost[$postVar])) {
                        $this->postMessage('Email Address is invalid');
                    }
                    break;

                //validate and verify password
                case 'password':
                    if ($item['verify'] === true) {
                        //validate password against other
                        if (!$this->verifyPassword($this->cleanPost['password'], $this->cleanPost['password2'])) {
                            $this->postMessage('Passwords do not match');
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (empty($this->cleanPost[$postVar]) && $item['req'] === 1) {
                            $this->postMessage($postVar . ': Please enter a password');
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                //validate checkboxes
                case 'checkbox':

                    if ($item['req'] === 1 && $this->validateCheckBox($postVar) === 0) {
                        $this->postMessage($postVar . ' must be checked');
                    } else {
                        $this->cleanPost[$postVar] = $this->validateCheckBox($postVar);
                    }
                    break;


                //handle url
                case 'url':
                    //first we need to handle making the url format properly
                    if(isset($this->cleanPost[$postVar])){
                        $url = $this->validUrl($this->cleanPost[$postVar]);

                        //now we do the final checking of the url and make sure it is a valid url before we move forwards
                        if ($item['req'] === 1 && $url === null) {
                            $this->postMessage($postVar . ' must be a valid URL');
                        }else{
                            $this->cleanPost[$postVar] = $url;
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                //handle text and text areas
                case 'text':
                case 'textarea':

                    if (isset($_POST[$postVar])) {

                        //check for a bypass on the min required characters
                        if (isset($item['bypass']) && $item['bypass'] === true || $this->minBypass === true) {

                            $bypassMinCheck = true;

                        } else {

                            $bypassMinCheck = false;
                        }

                        //process the item
                        if ($item['req'] === 1 && $bypassMinCheck === false && strlen($this->cleanPost[$postVar]) < 2) {

                            $this->postMessage($postVar . ' is too short');

                        } else {

                            if (!empty($this->cleanPost[$postVar]) && $bypassMinCheck === false) {

                                if (strlen($_POST[$postVar]) < 2) {

                                    $this->postMessage($postVar . ' is too short');

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                //handle other inputs
                default:
                    if (empty($_POST[$postVar]) && $item['req'] === 1) {
                        $this->postMessage($postVar . ' cannot be left empty');
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
} else {
    return false;
}

//return the success or failure of the prepost test
if (empty($this->message)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: How does the getPost(); method work? You might add the relevant code from those method that get the result after you submit (no need to write all the input creating methods, for example). Any error is likely to be there

Comment: Adding in more code from the class if that helps.

Comment: http://184.71.16.158/localSearchMaster/SEO  that is a sample of the problem if you submit one form it processes the tests for all instances